# Annoying dog stole the artifact! How do I get it back

Tags: undertale

So I was about to go to undine but then there was a statue!

> I gave the statue an umbrella and it started to play a song and gave me music directions... So I go to the piano in the other room and play the notes it gave me, and a door opens!

But when I go to collect the artifact it says I have "Too many dog" when I drop the dog it takes my artifact!

How do I get it back? Or is it used for a later battle? I also searched Google and Arqade part of SE.

Comment: I find it kinda sad that you are trying to find an answer to this before even completing the game first...

Comment: @Karlyr I already beat ASGORE and flowey

Comment: I edited your question into a spoiler tag, to prevent people from accidentally reading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sure you don't have something special in your inventory after that event ?

You actually have an item that could qualify as a powerful artifact, The "Dog Residue" fills your inventory with "Dog Salads" and other "Dog Residue". Granting theoretical infinite money (with the Temmie shop) and infinite healing items (Dog salads).

Answer (score 2):

You will not be getting the artifact back.  There is no way to retrieve it once it is absorbed.